# Which country or countries inspired the post-communism Polish higher education system?

Tags: germany, education, eu, poland

Which country or countries inspired the post-communism Polish higher education system?

Is the current Polish higher education system modeled after the German system of higher education?

Answer (score 1):

The higher-education system is inspired by [Humboldt's model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_education_in_Poland) and  [guided by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_Poland#Tertiary_education) standards for higher-education defined by the [Bologna process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_Process), which was "signed by education ministers from 29 European countries in 1999" and has since been adopted by [48 countries](http://www.ehea.info/page-full_members).

Comment: ["The two-tier system was instituted in Poland well before it was suggested by the Bologna declaration."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_education_in_Poland) so the Bologna agreement appears to be something Poland agreed to along the way, not the inspiration itself.

Comment: @Anyon The same article mentions the impact of the Bologna process, which surely means it provided inspiration.