# Does the Portuguese higher education system follow Humboldt's model?

Tags: poland, portugal

According to the other question on Academia SE, the Polish higher education system closely resembles the German one:

- [Which country or countries inspired the post-communism Polish higher education system?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/153982/which-country-or-countries-inspired-the-post-communism-polish-higher-education-s)

Polish higher education follows [Humboldt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_von_Humboldt)'s model so does German education. I personally hate [Humboldt's model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humboldtian_model_of_higher_education) as it is a time-hog in the case of undergraduate and masters levels.

Does the Portuguese higher education system follow Humbolt's model?

If No, which model do they follow?

Comment: The answer to the other question mentions the Balogna Process as a codification of Humbolt's model, and Portugal is a signatory thereof. So, the answer would appear to be "yes" for Portugal and most of Europe. Is this the sort of answer you had in mind, or am I missing something?

Comment: @cag51, actually, I am trying to understand if moving from Poland/Germany to Portugal will be able to offer me a different kind of higher education experience as I am fed up with these two countries.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that OP hates the Humboldt model, as its focus on character development defined academia, with its great successes, in the past. If one did not like it, in olden times, academia would not have been one's target anyway and one probably would have more chosen a vocational route. Today, OP will be pleased to know (me less so), it is increasingly eroded and is moving towards a more practical model focusing on concrete employability skills. OP should probably also have a look at the Anglo-Saxon model and countries which support it if it would better suit OP's requirements.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what exactly  you consider a waste of time?

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX, Okay. The problem with the model is: teachers throw some books to the students and tell students to learn by themselves. Lectures are totally useless as they are unintelligible and full of either formal math symbolic notations or badly designed without considering student-psychology. Asking questions is considered as a Taboo and disturbance in the classroom.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Portugal's basic education system does follow Humboldt's model. In university, it mostly depends on the institution you choose to study on. I don't know what kind of degree you're thinking about pursuing, but investigate the various universities that offer that degree and it's culture / philosophy.